# An essential formula for reconstructing the Poisson bivector from a Poisson bracket

Tags: differential-geometry, vector-fields, poisson-geometry

This was essentially addressed in [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2164092/poisson-bivector-induced-by-a-poisson-manifold). Nick's comment suggests to use that $\left\{f,g \right\}=\sum_{i,j} \frac{\partial f}{\partial x^i} \frac{\partial g}{\partial x^j} \left\{ x_i, x_j \right\}$ on some coordinate neighborhood, but I can't figure out why this is.

I know that $\left\{ f, \cdot \right\}$ and $\left\{ \cdot, g \right\}$ are both derivations, so $X_f(g) = X_f(x_j) \frac{\partial g}{\partial x^j}$. So I'd like to show that $X_f(\cdot) = \left\{ \frac{\partial f}{\partial x^i} x_i, \cdot \right\}$. I get that, if $df=df_1$ on some neighborhood, then $f-f_1$ is a constant on that neighborhood and since $\left\{\cdot , g \right\}$ is a derivation for any $g$, we have that $\left\{f-f_1, g \right\} = 0$ for any $g$ on the coordinate neighborhood. I'd like to use this fact, but I don't see why we necessarily have that $df = d \left( \frac{\partial f}{\partial x^i} x_i \right)$, because the right hand side is $ df + d \left( \frac{\partial f}{\partial x^i} \right)x_i$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you remark $df$ and $d(\sum_i \partial_i f x_i)$ are not the same. Indeed you have in general
$$\{f,g\}_x\neq \sum_i \{\partial_i f \,x_i,g\}_x$$
Remember also that you cannot pull out the $\partial_if$ without getting a $x_i\{\partial_i f,g\}_x$ term since this is a derivation.

What you do have is:
$$\{f,g\}_x= df(\{\cdot ,g\}_x)=\sum_i \partial_i f\ dx_i(\{\cdot ,g\}_x) = \sum_i \partial_if\  \{x_i,g\}_x$$

Comment: Ah good, so then $X_f=\sum_{i} \partial_i f X_{x_i}$. So then we reconstruct the bivector defined locally like $w(\alpha, \beta)= \sum_{i,j} \alpha_i \beta_j X_{x_i}(x_j)$ (where $X_h(\cdot) = \left\{ h, \cdot \right\}$)for $\alpha, \beta$ 1-forms and show that this doesn't depend on choice of coordinates $x_1, \ldots, x_n$?

Comment: For example.$ $